# jQuery Element Usage | Site Speed 101

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, turbolinks

I have an app with the added Gems:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-ui-sass-rails'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
```

Of course, I have a lot of other gems, but those are the ones I want to focus on right now.

The site loads kinda slow, and in my `application.js` I just call jquery.all for all the jquery stuff I load (Which I think I don't even need)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.masonry.min.js
//= require twitter/bootstrap
//= require flatuipro
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

My app isn't that big, and I don't think I need all of that stuff from jquery. But because im a little new (Hi all) I don't quite know WHAT EXACT plugins, widgets, elements i use to require them in my application.js so I DONT HAVE to call just jquery.all.

Besides that a lot of Thinks are not loaded from Turbolinks and a User have to F5 the page to get all the elements loaded.

**For example**: This is what gets loaded on EVERY Page:

```
 <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/twitter-bootstrap-static/fontawesome.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/devise-forms.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/flat-ui.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/flatuipro-demo.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/pages.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/shows.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/styles.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/users.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.core.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.widget.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.accordion.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.position.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.menu.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.datepicker.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.mouse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.draggable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.resizable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.dialog.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.droppable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-blind.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-bounce.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-clip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-drop.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fade.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-fold.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-highlight.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-pulsate.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-scale.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-shake.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-slide.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.effect-transfer.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.progressbar.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.selectable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.slider.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.sortable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.spinner.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.tabs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.all.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.masonry.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-scrollspy.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tab.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-popover.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-carousel.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-typeahead.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-affix.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap-select.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap-switch.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/flatui-checkbox.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/flatui-radio.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.tagsinput.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.placeholder.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.stacktable.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/flatuipro.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/clips.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/flatuipro-demo.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/pages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/shows.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/users.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

Could someone explain to me what is happening with Turbolinks and how to handle that jQuery Mess?

[jQuery UI Sass Rails](https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails), [My Repository](https://github.com/Theminijohn/myapp)

Comment: Hi Mini John, have you not heard about the rails Asset Pipeline. you should go through this link. Hope you will find all your answer. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Hey :) The asset pipeline is enabled by default. Which i am using.

Comment: Yes of course, its enabled by default. But You can make changes in your application.js and application.css according to you, whatever libraries you want.

Comment: I think i'll start by requiring only those libraries that i need by //= require. But the problem is i don't know what exact libraries i need :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with turbo links but I would for sure recommend getting rid of that `//= require jquery.ui.all` call. An easy way to deal with jQuery UI stuff is to just manually call the libraries in the head tag for development:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

Then once you know what parts of the library you need, just download a custom package with only the features you need from http://jqueryui.com/download/ and just put the js file in your `assets/javascripts` folder. You can do this with most of the libraries you'll need as features from some of them might be redundant. That `//= require_tree .` call at the end of the manifest file will call all the js files in your `assets/javascripts` folder.

Comment: For the moment i guess this is a solution. Thank you.